# Запускать python file каждые три часа

Tags: python, scheduler

Я уже пробовал запускать через планировщик задач на Windows, но он то срабатывал, то нет. Я попробовал написать python скрипт для этого:

```
import time
import os

while True:
   os.system('python Bot.py')
   time.sleep(10800)
```

Но и этот через раз срабатывал. В чём проблема, я не могу понять. Как мне написать скрипт, который будет запускать другой скрипт каждые 3 часа и чтобы это всегда исполнялось?

Comment: Можете попробовать использовать cron-таску

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html

Comment: используйте готовую библиотеку https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/